# R plotting - save as pdf with name specified in the function parameters

Tags: r, pdf, plot, save

Is this possible to specify name in the function that will save the plot with this name? I want the following:

```
somename <- function(data, **name**)

pdf("/Users/tanalytics1/Desktop/Rplots/**name**.pdf") *# would like name to be variable*

dev.off()
```

I tried to find the answer on the web but failed. Can you help with above? Thanks

Comment: Look at `sprintf`.

Comment: try:
`pdf(paste("/Users/tanalytics1/Desktop/Rplots/",name.,"pdf",sep="")`

Comment: sorry typo it should be:
`pdf(paste("/Users/tanalytics1/Desktop/Rplots/",name,".pdf",sep=""))`

Comment: Hey, thanks! It worked.

Also works pretty well when you specify name as: date().